# React state not updating accordingly

Tags: reactjs

I have a search component where the search result updates according to the search input, where if there is data returned from the API, it is rendered as a book grid, if there is no data, a message is displayed, and if the search input is empty, nothing is rendered.

My problem is that when `query` state updates the `searchResult` state does update but when I delete the search input so fast (make the search input empty), `query` becomes updates as an empty string but `searchResult` does not update according to it. What could be the problem?

Here is the code to the search component: (Note: I tried the `componentDidUpdate()` method and the `setState()` callback function but nothing worked)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// import "React Router" components
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import custom components
import Book from "./Book";

// import required API
import * as BooksAPI from "../BooksAPI";

export default class BookSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    searchResult: [],
  };

  handleInputChange = (query) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: query.trim(),
      },
      () => {
        if (query) {
          console.log(query);
          BooksAPI.search(query).then((books) => {
            this.setState({ searchResult: books });
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ searchResult: [] });
        }
      }
    );
  };

// componentDidUpdate(currentProps, currentState) {
//   if (currentState.query !== this.state.query && this.state.query) {
//     BooksAPI.search(this.state.query).then((books) => {
//       this.setState({ searchResult: books });
//     });
//   } else if (currentState.query !== this.state.query && !this.state.query) {
//     this.setState({ searchResult: [] });
//   }
// }

  render() {
    const { query, searchResult } = this.state;
    const { updateBookShelves } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <Link to="/" className="close-search">
            Close
          </Link>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by title or author"
              value={query}
              onChange={(event) => this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-books-results">
          <ol className="books-grid">
            { searchResult.error ? 
                <p>No results matching your search</p>
               : searchResult.map((book) => (
                  <Book
                    key={book.id}
                    book={book}
                    updateBookShelves={updateBookShelves}
                  />
                ))
              )
            ) )}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this solution since it is using `setState` inside callback of other `setState` but you can give it a try.

I think you can probably need to use `setTimeout` before calling api for data and before checking if `query` exist or not we can set `timeout` to null so it will not call unwanted api calls.

```
  handleInputChange = query => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: query.trim()
      },
      () => {
        if (this.timeout) {
          clearTimeout(this.timeout);
          this.timeout = null;
        }
        if (query) {
          this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            BooksAPI.search(query).then(books => {
              this.setState({ searchResult: books });
            });
          }, 800);
        } else {
          this.setState({ searchResult: [] });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```